# SQL Query: Looking to calculate difference between two columns both in different tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

I'm looking to calculate the difference between the sum of two different columns in two different tables. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT sum(amount)
FROM variable_in
where user_id='111111'
minus
SELECT sum(amount)
FROM variable_out
where user_id='111111'
```

When I do this, I just get an output of the first query results. How do I have it execute both queries (for the in and out tables) as well as have it minus the variable_out total for the amount column? Since they are both going to be positive integers.

Thanks in advance! Most of the other tips I've seen have been overly complex compared to my issue.

Comment: If the query in your question runs, then you are not using MySQL, so I removed the tag.

Comment: Do you understand why your attempt didn't work? "minus" is a set operation (as in "set theory"), not an arithmetic operation. Your first subquery returns one row, with a single column, of number data type. The second query also returns one row, and importantly, with a single column of data type. (If there was a mismatch in the number of COLUMNS or their data types, you would get a compilation error). Then, since the row from the second query is different from the first, the set-theoretic "minus" simply keeps the first row and returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving the queries to the `from` clause and using `-`:

```
SELECT in_amount - out_amount
FROM (SELECT sum(amount) as in_amount
      FROM variable_in
      WHERE user_id = '111111'
     ) i CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT sum(amount) as out_amount
      FROM variable_out
      WHERE user_id = '111111'
     ) o;
```

Your query is confusing the set operation "minus" with the numerical operator `-`.  Admittedly, they do have the same name.  But `minus` works with sets, not numbers.

I should point out that you can put the nested queries in the `FROM` clause and use the results like numbers ("scalar subqueries"):

```
SELECT ((SELECT sum(amount) as in_amount
         FROM variable_in
         WHERE user_id = '111111'
        ) -
        (SELECT sum(amount) as out_amount
         FROM variable_out
         WHERE user_id = '111111'
        ) o
       ) as diff
FROM dual;
```

Comment: I guess you mean "SELECT clause" in the second part. And you forgot to remove the `o` alias.

Comment: I was able to get the query to run properly! Thanks for the help, I used the same method that Gordon mentioned prior to reading the response! Thanks everyone :D

Comment: The second version must select FROM something, too (usually from dual).

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple...

```
select

   (select sum(amount) from variable_in where user_id='111111')
      -
   (select sum(amount) from variable_out where user_id='111111')

as amount;
```

Comment: @mathguy:: In mssql, you don't need a FROM

Comment: @jmoreno -   How about in Oracle? Please see the tags.

Comment: @mathguy: I believe DB2 and oracle have a dummy table with a single row in it for the same purpose, called DUAL.

Comment: @mathguy: that tag was added later, and the answer doesn't need to work without modification to be useful.

Comment: @jmoreno - perhaps, I wasn't sure which is why I didn't downvote. I notice that the solution is still not corrected.

Comment: well guys, 1000 programmers - 1000 opinions - it's the law... jmoreno, you are right :) FROM is not mandatory.